# Concat function in the Ajax response Php file breaks the script

Tags: php, sql, ajax, syntax, concatenation

I am trying to concatentate two variables in the php response file of an Ajax Script.

The Response file is the following:

```
$company_id=$_POST['company']:
$query="SELECT `contact_company`.`contact_id`, CONCAT(`surname`,' '.`fname`), `contact_company`.`company_id` FROM `seta`.`contact_company` AS `contact_company`, `seta`.`contacts` AS `contacts` WHERE `contact_company`.`contact_id` = `contacts`.`contact_id` AND `contact_company`.`company_id` ='".$company_id."' ";

$result=mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die ("Query to get data from contact_company table failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());


while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $contact_id=$row["contact_id"];
    $company_id=$row["company_id"];
    $contact_name=$row["CONCAT(`surname`,' ',`fname`)"];

    echo "<option value=\"$contact_id\">
         $contact_name
         </option>";
    }
```

While this syntax of CONCAT works perfectly in the other php files, it doesn't here. Can anybody please advise?
Thanks
Regards

Tommaso

Comment: Only `variables` are usable in `""`. Not — `functions`.

Comment: Little hint if you use single qoutes with echo you won't have to escape the double quotes ... `echo '<option value ="contact_id" ...'` is valid PHP code and eazier to maintain and read.

Comment: The variable `$company_id` is prone to SQL injection attacks. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php to prevent SQL injections

Comment: @AjAX. I see that makes sense now, but I am a bit confused, how would you solve the issue?

Comment: @RaymondNijland that variable comes from a Dropdown selection, so I guess no code can be injected

Comment: "RaymondNijland that variable comes from a Dropdown selection, so I guess no code can be injected ." Every $_GET, $_POST variables can not be trusted and can contain SQL injection attack vectors or other attack vectors

Comment: Sorry all good. I thought you meant the PHP `CONCAT`. %)P

Comment: @RaymondNijland, ok, I'll read the post. Thanks

Comment: "@RaymondNijland ..... but also, the only suggestion you have given, to replace " with ' and remove the escaping, breaks the code. Thanks for stopping this " Really because  `echo '<option value="$contact_id">
         $contact_name
         </option>';`  is valid PHP code and will not break the code.. Check this http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/78b02f87b0346e8867d339f9ef479bcf8b762d3d

Comment: I don't know why the ";" looks like a ":" but in the code it is ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aliases in your sql query. In this case it's fullname for the `CONCAT(..)` result.

```
$query="SELECT `contact_company`.`contact_id`, CONCAT(`surname`,' '.`fname`) as fullname, `contact_company`.`company_id` FROM `seta`.`contact_company` AS `contact_company`, `seta`.`contacts` AS `contacts` WHERE `contact_company`.`contact_id` = `contacts`.`contact_id` AND `contact_company`.`company_id` ='".$company_id."' ";
```

In your while loop replace with this:

```
$contact_name=$row["fullname"];
```

Also you ended your first statement with colon `:` instead of semi-colon `;`

Change your first line to:

```
$company_id=$_POST['company'];
```

Comment: To bad this answer still maintains the possible SQL injection on the $company_id variable

Comment: It's a simple script bro. Its solution is only one fold. Weird, its solution is the same for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the main problem here is that you ended a php statement with a colon instead of a semi-colon, i.e. `$_POST['company']:`.

Additionally, there is a problem in your MySQL `CONCAT` function. In your code it has:

```
`CONCAT(`surname`,' '.`fname`)`
```

This should separate each string literal or field with a comma. Additionally, you have a leading period `.` before `fname`, so like:

```
`CONCAT(`surname`, ' ', `fname`)`
```

Or if the `fname` field appears in more than one of the tables thus needs an alias, you should specify this:

```
`CONCAT(`surname`, ' ', `contacts`.`fname`)`
```

Fixed version below, please try this.

```
    $company_id = $_POST['company'];
    $query = "SELECT `contact_company`.`contact_id`, CONCAT(`surname`, ' ', `fname`) AS `fullname`, `contact_company`.`company_id` FROM `seta`.`contact_company` AS `contact_company`, `seta`.`contacts` AS `contacts` WHERE `contact_company`.`contact_id` = `contacts`.`contact_id` AND `contact_company`.`company_id` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($company_id) . "' ";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die("Query to get data from contact_company table failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $contact_id = $row["contact_id"];
        $company_id = $row["company_id"];
        $contact_name = $row["fullname"];

        echo "<option value=\"$contact_id\">
             $contact_name
             </option>";
    }
```

Comment: To bad this answer still maintains the possible SQL injection on the $company_id variable

Comment: Not my code, and not related to his concat issue, but you are right - I didn't see that. Added in a remedy for posterity.

Comment: @RaymondNijland as I said, the $company_id comes from a dropdown menu, no injection is possible.

Comment: @ajmedway the code works fine without the concat function

Comment: "RaymondNijland as I said, the $company_id comes from a dropdown menu, no injection is possible." Every $_GET, $_POST variables can not be trusted and can contain SQL injection attack vectors or other attack vectors

Comment: @TommasoLazzari "the code works fine without the concat function" - ah! Just seen it now, revising my answer :)

Comment: @TommasoLazzari - updated, please check. Additionally, I can confirm that RaymondNijland is correct in his assertions. For example, anyone could go into your dropdown menu in a browser's dom inspector e.g. Google Chrome inspector and manipulate the options there and submit bogus data. NEVER trust user submitted data. Note my answer uses this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php - but ideally you should be using [the more modern approach - PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: @ajmedway thanks for the comment, I will go back and check

Answer (score 0):

Your CONCAT syntax is wrong. Please see below for the right version.

```
$query="SELECT `contact_company`.`contact_id`, CONCAT(`surname`,' ',`fname`), `contact_company`.`company_id` FROM `seta`.`contact_company` AS `contact_company`, `seta`.`contacts` AS `contacts` WHERE `contact_company`.`contact_id` = `contacts`.`contact_id` AND `contact_company`.`company_id` ='".$company_id."' ";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: To bad this answer still maintains the possible SQL injection on the $company_id variable.

Comment: @Raymond - I am just helping out with the issue that the question has mentioned. The SQL injection part may not be implemented in the application. So please suggest it. Also you got your answer above in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with your sql CONCATE function, this should be :

`CONCAT(`surname`,' ',`fname`)`

```
 $company_id=$_POST['company']:
    $query="SELECT `contact_company`.`contact_id`, CONCAT(`surname`,' ',`fname`), `contact_company`.`company_id` FROM `seta`.`contact_company` AS `contact_company`, `seta`.`contacts` AS `contacts` WHERE `contact_company`.`contact_id` = `contacts`.`contact_id` AND `contact_company`.`company_id` ='".$company_id."' ";

    $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die ("Query to get data from contact_company table failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());


    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $contact_id=$row["contact_id"];
        $company_id=$row["company_id"];
        $contact_name=$row["CONCAT(`surname`,' ',`fname`)"];

        echo "<option value=\"$contact_id\">
             $contact_name
             </option>";
        }
```

Comment: To bad this answer still maintains the possible SQL injection on the $company_id variable